# Only after restarting Chrome browser: chrome.runtime.sendMessage() not sent, or chrome.runtime.onMessage listener function not called

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/asana2go/meaajmlecpkbjcofehfpjngpnpfpjlkd/related?hl=en-US) works fine...until I quit and restart Chrome.

After restarting Chrome, this line in my extension's content script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({msg: copyOrPrint, tasksOrSubtasks: tasksOrSubtasks, currentProjectIdOrSearch: currentProjectIdOrSearch, currentProjectName: currentProjectName, tasks: tasks});
```

is executed, I believe, because the prior line is a console.log() and I see its output in the console.

But because in my background script I have this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('background listener function');
    ...
```

and I **do not** see 'background listener function' in the console, I'm concluding that either the sendMessage isn't getting through or the onMessage listener is not getting called.

Can you think of any places where I could look to debug this? I'm using the page's devtools, the Inspect Popup devtools, and the background script page's devtools windows, and I've narrowed down to this but now I'm stumped.

Again, after restarting Chrome and seeing this failure to send or receive, I can remedy simply by reinstalling the extension and all works fine and I know the message is both sent and received and continues to work fine--until I quit and restart Chrome again. (This same behavior occurs if I run locally with Load Unpacked or published.)

Since the extension reinstall clears up the problem, perhaps my chrome.runtime.onInstalled listener is relevant? Here is the start of it (which ends with the snippet from my background script already included above):

```
'use strict';

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {

let md;
let outputTabId = null;
let messageObj = null;
let cssRules = null;
let requestMsg = null;

chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
    conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
      pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'app.asana.com'},
    })
    ],
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
  }]);
});

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) { // shortcut keys for copy, print
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: `ContentScript.sendEls('${command}');`});
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('background listener function');
    ...
```

(Background: this is my first extension and it's not trivial, so I may well have something wrong! I'm sorry not to include a minimal and complete verifiable example, but the common message passing examples with the extension documentation don't exhibit this problem, and my large extension does. You should be able to repeat my problem by installing the extension linked above, but you will also need to use asana.com since my extension is a page_action for Asana.)

Thank you very much for any leads/ideas!

Larry

Comment: [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/10257301) ?

Answer (score 1):

My colleague solved this. The onMessage listener was incorrectly inside the onInstalled listener, as is shown in the last code block in the question.

I should have realized that when Chrome restarts each time (post initial installation of the extension) none of this code is executed/exists so there's no onMessage handler to run anymore. But I never saw it during weeks of development because I rarely close chrome! And since I have been in heavy development, I'm constantly doing re-installs of the extension and thus getting the onMessage listener defined in my unique case--not so for most users!

Thanks...

Comment: There is chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {}); which fires when a profile that has this extension installed first starts up. This event is not fired when an incognito profile is started, even if this extension is operating in 'split' incognito mode. Here is the link to the docs: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onStartup